# Stop casting/disconnect box is tiny on my Android Cast app

Tags: google-cast

I'm familiarizing myself with the Google Cast SDK by building a small test application, following the [Cast SDK for Android guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender). I've created a standard `ActionBarActivity`-based app as the guide suggests (even though `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated... *shrug*) I've added all the library dependencies, added the necessary XML to `AndroidManifest.xml` and `menu_main.xml` and am using the `MediaRouteActionProvider` to handle device detection and to show/hide the Cast button in the action bar. All is working well, and the "Connect to device" box appears as it should when I tap the Cast Button.

[image: Connect to device screen]

However, when I tap the Cast button again to disconnect, the "Stop Casting" box appears but it is unusually small.

[image: Unusually small Stop Casting box]

The box is supposed to be wide enough to show the volume bar -- in my super-small version, the volume slider does in fact show up but it is unusably small. Compare to what it is supposed to look like, for example as in the YouTube app shown below.

[image: Correct appearance of Stop Casting box (YouTube app)]

Any idea what could be going on here? I am using basically the exact code that the [Cast SDK for Android guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) uses (the only addition being some custom `Button`s with `onClick` listeners to control the media playback and to start casting several different test streams (both audio and video.)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to changes that were made into the Media Router Support library and will be fixed in future updates to that library. If absolutely needed, the current workaround is to override that dialog.